# b64_md5 algorithm by Paul Johnston at http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5

Tags: php, javascript, curl, md5

i'm trying to use php curl to grab internet banking transaction. unfortunately the bank uses b64_md5 algorithm to pass the username and password to the server done by this script [md5.js](http://jsfiddle.net/AAhGD/) . i've googled a php function to simulate this. but i can find something help.

here is their code to generate the password

```
function checkScript(){
    pCheckScript.innerHTML = "";
    document.form_000001.pSubmit.disabled = false;
    document.form_000001.pCancel.disabled = false;
    document.form_000001.challenge.value = "[B@6be16be1"
    document.form_000001.login_name.focus();}
function submitForm(){
    var vPassword = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < document.form_000001.password.value.length; i++)vPassword = vPassword + "*";
    document.form_000001.login_name.size = 1;
    document.form_000001.password.size = 1;
    document.form_000001.login_name.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.form_000001.password.style.visibility = "hidden";
    textLoginName.innerHTML = document.form_000001.login_name.value;
    textLoginPassword.innerHTML = vPassword;
    document.form_000001.login_name.value = b64_md5(document.form_000001.login_name.value.toLowerCase());
    document.form_000001.password.value = b64_md5(b64_md5(document.form_000001.password.value) + document.form_000001.challenge.value);
    return true;}
```

the queston is, how to build php function to simulate this.

Comment: 34 questions, just 6 upvotes cast. Seems low.

Comment: It sounds like that `b64_md5` function returns a base 64 encoded md5 hash. Couldn't you just use `base64_encode(md5('string'));`? Make sure to notice that the password does this 2x, adding the "challenge" the second time around.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that uses [`base64_encode`](http://ca.php.net/base64_encode) and [`md5`](http://ca.php.net/md5).

```
<?php

// This assumes that the challenge never changes.
$challenge = '[B@6be16be1';

$username = base64_encode(md5(strtolower('username')));
$password = base64_encode(md5(base64_encode(md5('password')) . $challenge));
```